# Laravel How to clear session after display in specific page

Tags: php, laravel, session

I can store input value in session and display it in blade, but when I back to form and add new item, the previous item still in the session and can't display the new one!! I tried to add forget to session but didn't work, I'm using ajax to pass value to controller

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_getbids', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'addItem',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[country=_token]').val(),
        'country': $('input[name=country]').val() },
    success: function(data) {
   }, });
   $('#country').val('');});
```

**Controller**

```
  public function addItem(Request $request) {

   $request->session()->put('country', $request->country);

    }
```

**customer.blade**

```
    <div class="alert alert-success">
         {{Session::get('country')}} 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [`flash`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data) method

```
$request->session()->flash('country', $request->country);
```

Comment: its flush() method not flash().

Comment: Thank you your answer is wotking but can only use session variable once I know that

Comment: it's useful for the short-lived message.

Answer (score 5):

if i get u correctly,

```
session->flush();
```

will flush away all the session data, instead use

```
session->forget('key');
```

with the key parameter, you are specifying which data you wish to clear...

Comment: but I want to keep user login data!!! I tried  $request->session()->flush('country'); also kick me out from login and have to log in again!!!

Comment: refer below link for more information.   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-array-element-from-session

Answer (score 2):

You should try this add below code in your controller:

```
if($request->session()->has('country') && $request->session()->get('country') != '') {
  $request->session()->forget('country');
} else {
  $request->session()->put('country', $request->country);
}
```